# XAML ListSource binding from multiple objects

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a XAML view in which I am binding to a ViewModel and an ObservableCollection (Games) of type GAME_TBL

```
<ListView x:Name="GameListView"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Games}"
          ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped"
          CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
          RowHeight="120">
```

I am referencing properties of that GAME_TBL object like so

```
        <Label Text="{Binding GAME_NAME}"
               Style="{StaticResource GameListTitle}" />
```

However, I want to style the list rows and tried to bind to an object that is not a property of GAME_TBL

```
        <BoxView Grid.Column="0"
                 Grid.Row="0"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                 Grid.RowSpan="5"
                 BackgroundColor="{Binding BoxViewStyle}"/>
```

Code behind from same ViewModel

```
    public Color BoxViewStyle

    {

        get { return _boxViewStyle; }

        set
        {

            _boxViewStyle = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BoxViewStyle));


        }

    }
```

When the ViewModel is called I then set it like this

```
  BoxViewStyle = Color.FromHex("#000000");
```

However it hasn't worked

I think it's something to do with me declaring the entire ListView to have an ItemSource which is the OS, but then trying to use an object outside of that without explicitly referencing it? Might be wrong about that.

Comment: you want every row in the list to use the same BoxViewStyle?

Comment: no that was just to get things working stage by stage - I wanted to know I could bind the color first, then I was going to write a method that would alternate the colours every row

Comment: Not a full answer, but I'd recommend the 'RelativeSource' binding capabilities just added to Xamarin Forms 4.3

Answer (score 0):

The `BindingContext` for your list view is whatever data type `Games` is. Since the `BoxViewStyle` property lives in your ViewModel you can't bind to it from inside your `ListView.ItemTemplate`. You need to specify the source for your `Binding`.

Name your main ContentPage element. `x:Name="mainElement"`

When you set your BoxViewStyle binding specify the source:

```
<BoxView Grid.Column="0"
         Grid.Row="0"
         Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
         Grid.RowSpan="5"
         BackgroundColor="{Binding BoxViewStyle, Source={x:Reference mainElement}"/>
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the relationship here. Can BoxViewStyle still reside in ViewModel? I have a content page containing two views. Following your advice I named the relevant View (x:Name) and put that reference in the BackgroundColor, but it made no difference, the color still is not being applied

Comment: Just to check I have done what you intended, I moved BoxViewStyle out of the view model and into the code behind for the view itself - correct? That's solved this step at least ....

Comment: Moving it to the code behind will work, but then you're going to be moving out of the MVVM architecture. The property you're trying to bind to (BoxViewStyle) is in the ViewModel. You need to tell you're Binding inside of your DataTemplate where to look for that binding. Name an element who's binding context is your ViewModel and then tell your BoxViewStyle Binding source is that named element.

Comment: Again thanks for the ongoing help. I thought I had done that correctly but it didn't work. Where I have a situation such as I described (a view inside a content page) is it important which one of them I name and use as the reference?

Comment: the view that you name as the source needs to have your viewmodel as the binding context.

Answer (score -1):

> no that was just to get things working stage by stage - I wanted to know I could bind the color first, then I was going to write a method that would alternate the colours every row

If you want to have the same color for ListView row, you can create BoxViewStyle color property in ViewModel, as ottermatic said that BoxViewStyle property is in ViewModel, so you can not bind it for ListView datetemplate, so you name your listview as list firstly, find list's BindingContext.BoxViewStyle.

```
 <ListView x:Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding games}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="{Binding GAME_NAME}" />
                            <BoxView BackgroundColor="{Binding BindingContext.BoxViewStyle, Source={x:Reference list}}" />
                        </StackLayout>

                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

If you want to alternate the colors every ListView row, I suggest you can create BoxViewStyle in model, according to ListView row index to change color.

```
<ListView x:Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding games}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="{Binding GAME_NAME}" />
                            <BoxView BackgroundColor="{Binding BoxViewStyle}" />
                        </StackLayout>

                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Model.cs:

```
 public class Game
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string GAME_NAME { get; set; }
    public Color BoxViewStyle
    {
        get
        {
            if (Index % 2 == 0)
            {
                return Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                return Color.Blue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel.cs:

```
public class GameViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Game> games { get; set; }

    public GameViewModel()
    {
        games = new ObservableCollection<Game>()
        {
            new Game(){Index=0,GAME_NAME="game 1"},
            new Game(){Index=1,GAME_NAME="game 2"},
            new Game(){Index=2,GAME_NAME="game 3"},
            new Game(){Index=3,GAME_NAME="game 4"},
            new Game(){Index=4,GAME_NAME="game 5"}

        };
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't include an incrementer for index? I have done so but am confused because in a list of 12 items, the BoxViewStyle was only called six times in total?

Comment: What is especially weird is if I just bind the background color to my BoxViewStyle, every cell will be correctly coloured - it's when I want to altermate it that for whatever reason when I put a debug statement in there, it only seems to get called one time in two?

Comment: @Journeyman, what is your problem now? Can you provide some code about your question here? Because I guess that my reply first part code have solved your original question.

Comment: Your code sample wasn't complete, as mentioned it neglected an incrementer for index,but that's fine easy spot. The issue I have is that it doesn't work consistently for the Xamarin platforms - the iOS version is OK, has alternate colouring. The Android version does not, there's no obvious pattern